# Быстрая отрисовка таблицы  чата ios

Tags: ios, uikit

Есть приложение, пускай в нём будет 2 экрана. На одном список контактов, на втором - чаты. При переходе от экрана контактов в экран чатов таблица чатов моментально начинает отрисовываться в памяти на главном потоке, что вызывает лаг анимации перехода на новое окно. Может кто знает как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 2):

Если приложение под iOS7, то можно воспользоваться новым методoм UIView

```
- (BOOL)drawViewHierarchyInRect:(CGRect)rect afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates
```

Этот метод рисует всю view и ее subviews в текущий графический контекст, то есть вы можете запомнить таблицу чатов в UIImageView. Когда происходит анимация - показывайте эту UIImageView, когда анимация закончится - убирайте ее и обновляйте таблицу чатов реальным контентом.

Вот пример как сохранить view в виде картинки:

```
- (UIImageView*)takeSnapshot:(UIView*)view
{
    UIImageView *snapshot = nil;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    if([view drawViewHierarchyInRect:inView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES])
    {
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        snapshot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapshot;
}
```

Comment: Ого, интересный метод! Спасибо большое, но это немного не то)